# How to avoid NaN values when I use frame['Colum'].map(dict)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have the following dataset frame1

| Color | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Shirt |
| White | Shoes |
| Yellow | Shirt |
| Green | Shoes |

I want to set all the colors for Shoes item to be "Blue", I use map

```
x = {"Shoes": "Blue"}
fr1["Color"] = fr1["Item"].map(x)
```

I expected the following result

| Color | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Red | Shirt |
| Blue | Shoes |
| Yellow | Shirt |
| Blue | Shoes |

Instead I got this

| Color | Item |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | Shirt |
| Blue | Shoes |
| NaN | Shirt |
| Blue | Shoes |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either only use the rows with a valid key with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
x = {"Shoes": "Blue"}
m = fr1["Item"].isin(list(x))
fr1.loc[m, "Color"] = fr1.loc[m, "Item"].map(x)
```

Or [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
fr1["Color"] = fr1["Item"].map(x).fillna(fr1["Color"])
```